Attributes not applied in splash screen
I have simple splash_background.xml

<item android:drawable="?attr/main_background" />

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</item>

Which is used in style:
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>

Which is used in SplashActivity:
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.screens.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 

But the system not respects ?attr/main_background which is used for light and dark themes.
If I use hardcoded color like colors/red, the background color changed accordingly, but with attr it is not work.
What can be the reason? I want to make it work for light and dark modes.

What is your min supported android version?

min supported api 23+
